# Multi row pandas dataframe to multi column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot

I have pandas data frame:

```
d2 = {'F': ['apple', 'grap','figs'], 'score': [10,20,15],'week': [1,1,1]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

d1 = {'F': ['apple', 'grap','figs'], 'score': [20,30,35],'week': [2,2,2]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)

df=pd.concat([df1,df2])

     F  score   week
0   apple   20  2
1   grap    30  2
2   figs    35  2
0   apple   10  1
1   grap    20  1
2   figs    15  1
```

I want to have each F name as column like (***It is desirable result***):

```
week  apple grap figs 
1      20    30   35   
2      10    20   15
```

I tried set_index:

```
print (df.set_index('F').T)
```

but the result is not what I want:

```
F      apple  grap  figs  apple  grap  figs
score     20    30    35     10    20    15
week       2     2     2      1     1     1
```

Is there any method or function I can use directly to get the result I need?

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: I stated the desirable result above

Comment: Use `df.sort_values(['F','week']).reset_index()`?

Comment: I think you want `df.pivot('week', 'F', 'score')`, but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Edit to handle updated question with new expected results:

```
df.pivot('week','F','score').reset_index()
```

Output:

```
F  week  apple  figs  grap
0     1     10    15    20
1     2     20    35    30
```

Use `sort_values`:

```
df.sort_values(['F','week']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
       F  score  week
0  apple     10     1
1  apple     20     2
2   figs     15     1
3   figs     35     2
4   grap     20     1
5   grap     30     2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .T, Transpose function after sorting to get the desired output.

```
newdf=df.sort_values(['F','week']).T
```

Output

```
F      apple  apple  figs  figs  grap  grap
score     10    20    15     35    20    30
week       1     2     1      2     1     2
```